# Why is it when I calculate the radius of convergence R, the answer is always $\frac{1}{R}$?

Tags: power-series

Let me explain. So take the series

- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^nn^4(x-1)^n$

In order to find the radius of convergence for this power series, I used the ratio test

- $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{2(n+1)^4(x-1)^{n+1}}{2n^4(x-1)^n}|$

and got $|x| < 2$ but then the radius of convergence was $R = \frac{1}{2}$

Is the radius of convergence $R$ obtained by putting it over 1? I'm really confused

Edit: Calculated limit wrong. Sorry

Comment: Why do you use ratio test here?

Comment: ...And what would it give for the geometric progression?

Comment: @EgorIvanov Not sure, maybe I should have used the root test?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I'm assuming 1/2 but why

Comment: @BillCogn Do you know anything about Cauchy-Hadamard theorem?

Comment: @EgorIvanov No but after reading a bit, it mentions 1/R but I haven't done complex analysis yet

Comment: It can be proven in real analysis in the same way. Moreover usually it is proven in real case first and then when complex analysis is studied it is said: "the proof is similar to real analysis". So you can look it through. The idea is simple: to compare the series with geometric progression: $a_nx^n = (\sqrt[n]{a_n}x)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate the limit, you get $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{2(n+1)^4(x-1)^{n+1}}{2n^4(x-1)^n}\right| = 2|x-1|.$$ The ratio test gives convergence so long as $L<1,$ so you need $2|x-1|<1,$ meaning $|x-1|<\frac{1}{2}.$ This exactly says that the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: @BillCogn: I don't think that was where you went wrong! You seem to think that the radius of convergence is $\lim\left |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right |$ if this limit exists; whereas in fact it is $\lim\left |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right |$.

Comment: @TonyK Ahh that's it

Comment: @TonyK Is there a reason why it happens to be the reciprocal of the ratio test?

Comment: To understand "the reason", try the ratio test on a geometric series.  (As in the hint by Amateur-Algebraist.)

Comment: @GEdgar: That doesn't help, if by "geometric series" you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ $-$ the limits of $\left |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right |$ and $\left |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right |$ are the same.

Comment: Try the geometric series $\sum r^n x^n$, where $r>0$ is a given constant.

Comment: That's better :-)